# Installation for Gstreamer plugins, avi demuxer missing

Tags: c, gstreamer

I am trying to run some Command line:

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///home/xxx/VSCode/C++/Gstreamer/resource/traffic.avi
```

But there was some problem, it complained it couldn't find avi demuxer

```
Missing element: Audio Video Interleave (AVI) demuxer
```

I thought that it was missing and i tried to reinstall the program again using [this link for Ubuntu](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-linux.html?gi-language=c). However everything was ok and the file was up-to-date

When I tried to see how many plugins I have using gst-inspect,

```
>>>>> gst-inspect-1.0
...............
Total count: 25 plugins, 253 features
```

Is it normal to have only 25 plugins? Seem to be missing quite a bit of plugins or is there some linking process you would need to do when installing gstreamer

Thanks

========================================================================
Edited: To present more diagnostic information as suggested

- Location of gst-inspect-1.0

  ```
  >> which gst-inspect-1.0
  >> /home/xxx/anaconda3/bin/gst-inspect-1.0
  ```

It is quite surprising to me that gst-inspect-1.0 is over in this folder, anaconda

- Version of gst inspect

  ```
   >> gst-inspect-1.0 --version
   gst-inspect-1.0 version 1.14.0
   GStreamer 1.14.0
   Unknown package origin
  ```
- Dynamic link required

  ```
    >> ldd $(which gst-inspect-1.0)
       linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff81cef000)
       libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 => /home/xxx/anaconda3/bin/.. /lib/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 (0x00007ff0bbcf5000)
       libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /home/xxx/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ff0bc40d000)
       libglib-2.0.so.0 => /home/xxx/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ff0bc2f0000)
       libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff0bbad6000)
       libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff0bb6e5000)
       libffi.so.6 => /home/xxx/anaconda3/bin/../lib/./libffi.so.6 (0x00007ff0bb4dc000)
       libpcre.so.1 => /home/xxx/anaconda3/bin/../lib/./libpcre.so.1 (0x00007ff0bc277000)
       libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /home/xxx/anaconda3/bin/../lib/./libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ff0bc270000)
       libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff0bb13e000)
       librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007ff0baf36000)
       libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff0bad32000)
       /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff0bc23e000)
  ```

Comment: Its not normal. You should have installed all the gstreamer1.0-plugins-* .  Check  `aptitude show gstreamer1.0-plugins-good` .. or check presence of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstavi.so

Comment: @nayana it is present in the directory  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstavi.so. So the problem is with linking...any ways i could make a clean installation or ...  Also is there a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer1.0  folder being installed

Comment: If you really have installed via apt-get there is no chance you would have these problems. Please add more details if you build something on your own. These infos `which gst-inspect-1.0` then `gst-inspect-1.0 --version` then `ldd $(which gst-inspect-1.0)` In any case if you are hacking things you may use GST_PLUGIN_PATH to point it to the /usr/..../gstreamer-1.0/ directory and LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point it to the actual libraries (this is more like override). Lastly please check `gst-inspect-1.0 -b` to check if you do not have everything blacklisted for some reason.